# In pigeonhole principle, what is the expected number of holes with no pigeons

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I am trying to understand pigeonhole principle and I am trying some random queries to further my understanding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

In pigeonhole principle, what is the expected number of holes which did not have any pigeons?
How do i get an intuition around this?
Thanks

Comment: The question relies on a missing premise. The pigeonhole *principle* doesn't involve any reference to any random process by which we might derive an expectation. It says something along the lines of "if n objects are put into m slots, with n > m > 0, then at least one slot must contain more than one object". That's the principle and it applies *no matter how objects are allocated to slots". You could always allocate all $n$ objects to one slot, or always allocate all $n$ objects to the emptiest available slot (breaking ties arbitrarily), but it wouldn't change the principle in any way.

Comment: Presumably you mean to specify some manner of allocating objects to slots, but that's nothing to do with the principle.

Answer (score 3):

As Kodiologist correctly writes, the Pigeonhole Principle is a combinatorial observation about the [Balls into Bins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_into_bins) problem when there are more balls than bins. Presumably, as a matter of terminology, you meant to ask about the expected number of empty bins in the *ball into bins* problem.

Suppose you have $m$ bins and $n$ balls. The probability that a specific bin will remain empty is $\left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)^n$. This is also the expectation of the event that is 1 if it is empty, and 0 otherwise. By linearity of expectation, you can just sum this up for all bins. The expectation of the number of empty bins is therefore $m \left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)^n$

Answer (score 2):

The pigeonhole principle is a combinatorial rather than probabilistic statement. So, it makes no claims about expected value, just about cases in which collisions may happen, collisions must happen, or collisions must not happen. For example, if you have more holes than pigeons, then at least one of the holes will end up empty.